# Retrieving data from Vertica using Android app

Tags: android, vertica

I need to build an Android application to retrieve data from Vertica. May I know is this possible? If yes, what language can be used for communication between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is it possible?* **Yes!**

*How?* I know two ways, but **Web Service** as communication layer is best approach.

*What language?*  I suppose you're coding android app in java (not c or c++), so do it in **java**.

*Where to start?* My suggestion is **RESTful web service**, you can find good example [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/).